# Duplicate entries in database. ASP.NET - C# - SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, parameters, duplicates

Question: data gets duplicated when inserting into database. How do I not make duplicate entries in database?

I read about securing/ preventing SQL injection by not using the

```
texboxt1.text
```

So I tried using

```
parameters.add()
```

But the entries are duplicated for every insertion.

This is the image of the database...

[image]

This is my code

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = txtuser.Text;
        string firstname = txtfirst.Text;
        string lastname = txtlast.Text;
        string email = txtemail.Text;
        string password = txtpass.Text;
        string gender = rbgender.Text;
        string nationality = ddcountry.Text;

        string Connect_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(Connect_string);

        Connect.Open();

        string pass = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "MD5");
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Users] (username, firstname, lastname, email, password, gender, nationality) VALUES (@username, @firstname, @lastname, @email, @password, @gender, @nationality)", Connect);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstname);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationality", nationality); 
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();


        int success = Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (success > 0)
        {
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#12223");
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "You have successfully registered";
            Connect.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Your information has not been entered to database";
            Connect.Close();
        }
```

When I use
    INSERT INTO Table () VALUE '"+textbox1.text +"' 
it doesn't get duplicated but yeah, SQL injection-thingy.

Answer (score 5):

You have two calls to the ExecuteNonQuery which actually fires the command:

```
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationality", nationality); 
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //CALLED HERE First Time

    int success = Command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //CALLED HERE Second Time (This is the one you want)

    if (success > 0)
    {
        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#12223");
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "You have successfully registered";
        Connect.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the query twice, by these lines:

```
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

int success = Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Remove the first `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()` and leave the second one with the `int success`.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you Karl.